# Batch File - Infinite loop checking vpn connection

Tags: batch-file, command-line, automation, infinite-loop

I have this batch file to automate this process here at work of connecting to a vpn. It has some other steps it needs to take after the vpn connects, so I wrote a loop which constantly checks to see if there is a vpn connection. But even when the vpn connects, it can never break out of the loop. Please help.

this is the pertinent code

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Cisco Systems\VPN Client\ipsecdialer.exe" -c -sd -user %username% -pwd %vpn_password% "lifeline-ceacc.elluciancloud.com"

:loop
set length_of_file = 0
("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Cisco Systems\VPN Client\vpnclient.exe" stat) >_vpnstat.txt
PING -n 5 127.0.0.1>nul
set /p vpnstat=<_vpnstat.txt
call :strlen length_of_file vpnstat
echo %length_of_file%
::del _vpnstat.txt::
IF %length_of_file% LSS 46 goto :loop


::doing some other stuff here::


goto :eof

:strlen <resultVar> <stringVar>
(   
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "s=!%~2!#"
    set "len=0"
    for %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
        if "!s:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" ( 
            set /a "len+=%%P"
            set "s=!s:~%%P!"
        )
    )
)
( 
    endlocal
    set "%~1=%len%"
    exit /b
)
```

Comment: What does the file `_vpnstat.txt` contain in case connection is established, and what if not? I understand you are checking the length of the returned string to be 46 or more characters; instead of the complex computation of the string length you could use `if "%vpnstat:~45%"=="" goto :loop`; this uses sub-string expansion -- see `set /?`...

Comment: Well... ("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Cisco Systems\VPN Client\vpnclient.exe" stat) >_vpnstat.txt is the second line of code in the loop, so it contains the result of calling (vpnclient.exe stat). If there's no connection, the file should be 44 words long. If there is a connection, there should be close to 100.

Comment: I was hoping you provide some sample text... anyway, it *must* be a single line of text as you are reading it by redirecting into `set /P`; I recommend to put `echo(%vpnstat%` after the `set /P` command line for testing as `set /P` might dismiss some characters...

Comment: edit: Dude!  nvmd about what I was using. set yours as an answer. Your suggestion worked. :) ....... nevermind. didn't work. I jumped the gun

Answer (score 0):

```
set /p vpnstat=<_vpnstat.txt
IF "%vpnstat:~46%" equ "" goto loop
```

would be way easier...